# sql server datetime to float error

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, rounding-error

I trying to calculate work shift from as flollows by comparing the datetime::float value with 1/3 as follows:

```
select t, 
    cast( ( cast( cast(t as datetime) as float) - floor(cast( cast(t as datetime)  as float ) ) ) * 3.0 as decimal(38,30) ) x,
    floor( 
        ( cast( cast(t as datetime) as float) - floor(cast( cast(t as datetime)  as float ) ) ) * 3.0 
        ) x1
from ( values ('2019-01-01 00:00:00.0') , ('2019-01-01 07:59:59.0') , 
              ('2019-01-01 08:00:00.0') , ('2019-01-01 15:59:59.0') , 
              ('2019-01-01 16:00:00.0') , ('2019-01-01 23:59:59.0') ) test_sample(t)
```

But the result is confusing:

```
2019-01-01 00:00:00.0   0E-30   0.0
2019-01-01 07:59:59.0   0.999965277776937010000000000000    0.0
2019-01-01 08:00:00.0   1.000000000007276000000000000000    1.0
2019-01-01 15:59:59.0   1.999965277784212900000000000000    1.0
2019-01-01 16:00:00.0   1.999999999992724100000000000000    1.0 <----- inconsistency, expected 2.0
2019-01-01 23:59:59.0   2.999965277769661100000000000000    2.0
```

Why is 16:00:00  different from other values ?
What can I do to correctly work around this error (without comparing dates with lot of `case when`s ) ?

Comment: I don't understand why you are doing such a complicated series of casts.  We should probably fix that first.  But your answer likely has to do with floating point arithmetic, which is _not_ exact in SQL Server (or other languages).

Comment: Whatever you are trying to accomplish: just use **exact data type**: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ea1d00e805eccea2cba99e6b43152477. Float/real/double are approximate data types.

Comment: @Tim-Biegeleisen: I need to segment the 24 hours into several shifts, instead of using many `case when`s I can get the shift code in one pass. Honestly this idea comes from my previous experience in `postgresql` with epochtimes. I though I can do the same with datetime::float in `mssql`.

Comment: @lad2025: I am afraid they are still not consistent, look at the sharp clocks.If I `floor` on them I will get different results... :-(

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42670573/the-reason-behind-loss-of-precision-overflow-when-converting-decimal-or-numeric/42672264#42672264), about difference between float and numeric